# Why is this changed value read as the original after Utilities.sleep?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sleep

I have Google Sheets running in OnEdit(). When a cell in a specific row is changed to "completed" an email will be sent to the job owner. For now it pops up a browser message.

But I want to avoid sending an email in the case where the selection is accidental and gets changed again a few seconds later.

The surprising issue is that after running Utilities.sleep(10000) and re-reading the cell's value to make sure it's the same, even if it has been changed, it will read the value again as "completed". Is this something to do with the sleep function?

```
  if (changedColumn == stageColumnIndex) {
    var newValue = sheet.getRange(changedRow, changedColumn).getValue(); // read changed cell value before the sleep call

  if (newValue.toLowerCase() == "completed") {
    //  check again in a few seconds in case it was an accidental selection which was quickly changed
    Logger.log('Sleeping');
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    var checkedValue = sheet.getRange(changedRow, changedColumn).getValue();  //  read same cell value after sleep call but it is the same as newValue even when the cell was changed while sleeping
    Logger.log('newValue: ' + newValue);
    Logger.log('checkedValue: ' + checkedValue);

    var announceChange = (checkedValue == newValue);
    if (announceChange) {
      var streetIndex = 2;
      var street = sheet.getRange(changedRow, streetIndex).getValue();
      Browser.msgBox("Job completed at " + street + ".");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not knowing why this is happening: How quickly do you want this to respond to such a change? You could have the onEdit write a log to the Script Properties or cache consisting of location, timestamp and status and then run a scheduled script over it to determine the last state and send an email if it is at least x seconds old and "completed"

Comment: Its seems that a snapshot is given the script instance. I did some testing and confirmed what you found. Robin's idea is solid.

Comment: I wonder if putting a flush in here might solve your problem. `Utilities.sleep(10000);SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var checkedValue = sheet.getRange(changedRow, changedColumn).getValue();  `

Comment: The flush actually helps to see the changes but of course when you change the value during sleep it generates another onEdit trigger so you'll see the change occur and then the other onEdit runs and you won't see any change on that one unless you edit it again

Comment: I didn't know about the either the Properties Service or Cache Service so that's an instant win, thank you. By "run a scheduled script over it to determine the last state" do you mean like:"ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .after(10000)
   .create();"